# Python Performance Tuning with Datetime

Tags: python, performance, datetime

I am trying to tune a section of code to run faster. It is fundamentally datetime manipulation.

I tried a couple of options but the original one seemed faster, and yet "slow".

Following is the Code:

```
minDate = (df[time_variable].min()).replace(hour=0)
maxDate = (df[time_variable].max()).replace(hour=23) + timedelta(hours=1)
df["TC"] = df[time_variable]

print(datetime.now())
while (minDate <= maxDate):
    nextTime = minDate + timedelta(minutes=6)  
    #Choice 2
    #conditions = [(df[time_variable] > minDate) & (df[time_variable] <= nextTime)]
    #choices = [minDate]
    #df["TC"] = np.select(conditions, choices)
    
    #Choice 1
    df.loc[(df[time_variable] > minDate) & (df[time_variable] <= nextTime), "TC"] = minDate
    minDate = nextTime
print(datetime.now())
```

Currently this takes between 20-40 seconds.
I am trying to reduce to this to less than 2 seconds.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider *sorting* the dataframe and use a binary search so to do that in quasi-linear time instead of a quadratic time.

Comment: Can you edit your question and put there sample (small) input and expected output?

Comment: [`Profile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html) this code to determine where the time is being spent.